# Installable distro with customised kernel and selected packages

Tags: customization

How do I create a custom distro.

I have a 
- minimal installation with Preempt RT patched kernel 
- no graphic desktop
- it is a text based system for embedded application
- a selected set of packages

I need this to me converted into an installable iso image. The installer cab also be text based

Can anyone help

Thanks and regards

Partha

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Novo" or "ubuntu-builder" or  "remastersys" that would be perfect

Comment: I don't see those in my repositories. Where can they be obtained?